# Stuck on how to do model data in the right "Cake way"?

Tags: cakephp, database-design, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to build a tool to help my team plan events.  A partial diagram to explain my question:

[image: Diagram]

[Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U63bj.png)

`Actions` hasMany `Teams` with different roles (i.e. Lead, Secondary) via a hasManyThrough (`actions_teams`)

`Actions` are linked to other actions in a parent/child relationship via a hasManyThrough (`linkages`)

**REQUIRED:**
I'd like to be able to know, for a given `Action`.`id` that has an attached (`actions_team`) `Team`(s) in a given role, do those `Team`(s) have a `linkage` back to `Action`.`id` (i.e. lists `Action`.`id` as the parent in `linkages`)?

I've figured out how to do this in both controllers and even in views, by using loops and/or `Containable` to be able to highly control the data coming back.  However, I will ask this question so frequently, that I'd prefer to somehow implement it in the database itself.

The relation I need would seem to be a join table of 2 join tables? (`actions_teams` and `linkages`).  Or is the solution to use a `counterCache`?  I'm stuck.

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated. TIA!

Comment: It sounds like what you're talking about is a directed graph.  Are your action relationships through linkages acyclical?  For example, action A > action B > action A is not allowed.  If so, your action relationships may be modelled as a tree.  People have already written cakePHP behaviors and such to model trees.  Perhaps one of them already does what you're looking for.

Comment: @user2076809 I believe in my case A > B implies B > A.  I looked into the Tree Behaviour.  Follow up: If an `Action` can have many parent `Action`s does Tree still work? In my case specifically this would be one Team performing an action that simultaneously satisfied the requirements of 2+ other teams, which is plausible.  TIA!

Comment: Trees only require that there are no loops.  Thinking of a tree as having parent / child is a little misleading, since for a tree, it's more like is A related to B, doesn't matter what the relationship is that the tree is modelling.  One node can have many relationships to other nodes, whether that relationship is child, parent, or whatever.  It just needs to not have loops, otherwise traversing the whole tree wouldn't work, as there'd be no end points.

Comment: @user2076809 Thanks for this. I think I'll have to look much more closely as Trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption had to be made that the linkage was only 1 level (i.e., we cannot from a child check beyond its parent.  If your given action_id is the grandparent or great-grandparent of the team's action, this will NOT work.) Instead of creating 1 giant SQL statement with (potentially) derived tables, sub-selects, etc., start with a view to establish the "list of potential teams."

Without seeing actual data, create this view to make sure there is a distinct list (you may be able to avoid this view if these three fields comprise an unique index.)

```
CREATE VIEW vw_team_listing AS
SELECT DISTINCT team_id, action_id, action_role_id
FROM actions_teams;
```

{The case statement is because you asked, "do teams have a linkage back?"  You could just create a select statement for those teams that DO or DO NOT have a linkage (not both)}

```
SELECT vw_team_listing.team_id AS team_id,
CASE
WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM linkages
JOIN actions_teams
ON linkages.child_action_id = action_teams.action_id
WHERE linkages.parent_id = vw_team_listing.action_id
AND actions_teams.team_id = vw_team_listing.team_id
)
THEN 'Linked'
ELSE 'Not Linked'
END AS answer
FROM vw_team_listing
WHERE vw_team_listing.action_id = 'GIVEN_ACTION_ID'
AND vw_team_listing.action_role_id = 'GIVEN_ACTION_ROLE_ID';
```